# How to reference private instance variable in main.m

Tags: objective-c

I am leaning objective-c, and as shown below in the code, I created an interface with a private instance variable section. In the main.m, a pointer instance variable was created as shown below. what I want to know is how to send a message to one of private instance variable? Something as the following:

```
[ptr->_address XXX]..IS IT POSSIBLE
```

2- and how to initialise the private instance variables using

```
[[xxx alloc] initWithxxx]……IS IT POSSIBLE??
```

**main.m**

```
    MeAsImpl *ptr = [[MeAsImpl alloc] initWithCountry:@"DEU" andCity:@"KA" andAddress:@"xyzstrasse7"];

    NSLog(@"chip:[ %@ ]", ptr->_address);
    NSLog(@"chip:[ %p ]", structChipInitializerSegment);
    NSLog(@"chip:[ %@ ]", structChipInitializerSegment->chipName.self);
    NSLog(@"chip:[ %p ]", structChipInitializerSegment->chipName.self);
    NSLog(@"chip:[ %p ]", structChipInitializerSegment->numOfTotalChannels);
```

**.h**:

```
#import "ProtocolKidsSchedules.h"
#ifndef MeAsImpl_h
#define MeAsImpl_h

#endif /* MeAsImpl_h */

@interface MeAsImpl : NSObject<ProtocolKidsSchedules> {
    id<ProtocolKidsSchedules> _signee;
   NSString *_country;
    NSString *_city;
    NSString *_address;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ProtocolKidsSchedules> signee;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MeAsImpl *owner;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *country;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *address;

-(NSString *) signeeOfTheContract: (id<ProtocolKidsSchedules>) signee;
-(id) initWithCountry: (NSString *) country andCity: (NSString *) city andAddress: (NSString *) address;
-(id) initWithOnlyCity: (NSString *) city;
-(id) initWithOnlyAddress: (NSString *) address;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MeAsImpl.h"

@implementation MeAsImpl
@synthesize country, city, address;

-(BOOL)areChoresCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
   return completed;
}

-(BOOL)areHomeWorkCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
    return completed;
}

-(BOOL)doDerserveCookies:(BOOL)doDeserve {
        return doDeserve;
}

-(NSString *)signeeOfTheContract:(id<ProtocolKidsSchedules>)signee {
   return @"Signee is: ";
}
-(id)initWithCountry:(NSString *)country andCity:(NSString *)city andAddress:(NSString *)address {
    self->_countery = country;
    self->_city = city;
    self->_address = address;
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithOnlyCity:(NSString *)city {
    self->_city = city;
   return self;
}
-(id)initWithOnlyAddress:(NSString *)address {
    self->_address = address;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: FYI - based on the code you posted, you are following a very old and outdated Objective-C tutorial. You really should find a better tutorial. If the tutorial has you create explicit ivars and call `@synthesize` for all of your properties, then it is obsolete. And if the tutorial has you put ivars in the .h file, it is either obsolete or just bad.

Comment: would you please you please recommend a better tutorial and updated one?? and please can u correct my example the one posted above